# Writing a Program for homework, Cannot figure out how to add while loop inside my method to end the program if entered "stop"

Tags: java

These are the instructions for the program
During the tax season, every Friday A&A accounting firm provides assistance to people who prepare
their own tax returns. Their charges are as follows:
(a) If a person has low income (<=25,000) and the consulting time is less than or equal to 30
minutes, there are no charges; otherwise the service charges are 40% of the regular hourly rate
for the time over 30 minutes.
(b) For others, if the consulting time is less than or equal to 20 minutes, there are no service
charges; otherwise, service charges are 70% of the regular hourly rate for the time over 20
minutes.
For example, suppose that a person has low income (<25000), spent 1 hour and 15 minutes, and the
hourly rate is $70.00. The billing amount is 70.00 X 0.40 X (45/60) = $21.00)
Write a java program that prompt the user to enter the hourly rate, the total consulting time, and
income. The program should output the billing amount. Your program must be implemented using
method. Failure to do so will result in a zero for the program even if you have a correct running
program. You have to use the concept of methods.

******************************** here is my code *******************

```
package pack8;
import java.util.*;
public class class8 {


static Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
//Declare variables
double income;
double hourlyRate;
double consultingTime;
boolean incomeStatus;
String stoporgo;
class8.sayGreeting();
class8.stoporgo();

//Prompt the input from user
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter income:");
income=input.nextDouble();
if (income <= 25000)
incomeStatus = true;
else
incomeStatus = false;

//Prompt the user to enter the hourly rate
System.out.println("Enter hourly rate:");
hourlyRate= input.nextDouble();

//Prompt the total consulting time
System.out.println("Enter total consluting time(minutes):");
consultingTime= input.nextDouble();

System.out.println("The billing amount is : $"+billingAmount(hourlyRate, consultingTime, incomeStatus));
}

@SuppressWarnings("null")
public static void stoporgo() {
    System.out.println("Do you want to Continue or Stop:");
    console.next();
    Object stoporgo = null;
    while(console);
        if(stoporgo.equals("Stop")){
        break;
    }
}

private static String sayGreeting() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to A&A Accounting");
        System.out.println("Glad to help you determine your cost for filing 2012 taxes with us");

    return null;
}
/*Method takes as input the hourly rate , the total consulting time
* and a value indicating if the person has low income */
public static double billingAmount(double hourlyRate, double consultingTime,boolean incomeStatus)
{
double charges;
if(incomeStatus)

/* If low income (<=25,000) and the consulting time
* is less than or equal to 30 minutes
* there are no charges
*/
if(consultingTime <= 30)
charges = 0.0;

/*Otherwise the service charges are 40% of the
* regular hourly rate for the time over 30 minutes .
*/
else
charges = hourlyRate * 0.4 *
(consultingTime - 30) / 60;
/*, if the consulting time is less that or equal to 20 minutes
* there are two service charges ; otherwise service charges
* are 70% of the regular hourly rate for the time over 20 minutes

* */
else if (consultingTime <= 20)
charges =0.0;
else
charges = hourlyRate * 0.7 *
(consultingTime - 20) / 60;

return charges;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm having a very hard time on the (Do you want to continue or stop) part.

Comment: The `while` loop is not going to work because you are supplying a `Scanner` named `console`.  The `while` loop works with a `boolean`.

Comment: have you had any luck?

Comment: I tried the code below, still getting an error. Where break cannot be outside a loop or switch, which it is still in though...? hmm..

Comment: Check the `{` and `}`s within the code, make sure there is a block for the for loop and a block for the if statement.  Basically, if you count the amount of `{`s and `}`s they should be equal.

Comment: If you update the code in your answer I'll help, but won't give you the answer.

Comment: perfect! also had to delete the ; after stop apparently putting it outside the loop. Thank you very much for your help! life saver!

Comment: Only thing is, that even if I type Stop, the program continues. Ill post the code in a second!

Comment: Think about your logic.  It basically reads like this:  `while s is not equal to stop ask for user input then exit the program`.  I don't really think you even need the `while loop`

Comment: I don't even see it in the requirements for your homework that you need to continually ask the user for input.  Maybe you are trying to go above and beyond which is good.  Let me cook up a small example for you.

Comment: I'm not sure how to exit a program then without a while loop with a value equal to something that makes it break. Especially if its user inputted.

Comment: I'm going to add the pseudocode outline he wants me to follow.

Comment: check this out: https://gist.github.com/kmb385/cde0409fe5ca2fd6ee86

Comment: you should be editing your question as opposed to posting answers

Comment: Apologies, first time on this website.

Comment: I know, just trying to guide you.

Answer (score 0):

You have compare to the String returned by `console.next()`.

```
public static void stoporgo() {
    System.out.println("Do you want to Continue or Stop:");
    String s = "";
    while(!s.equals("Stop"));
        s = console.next();
        break;
    }
}
```

This will stay in the `while()` loop as the String `s` is not `"Stop"`

Answer (score 0):

```
package pack8;
import java.util.*;
public class class8 {


static Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
//Declare variables
double income;
double hourlyRate;
double consultingTime;
boolean incomeStatus;
String s;
String stoporgo;
class8.sayGreeting();
class8.stoporgo();

//Prompt the input from user
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter income:");
income=input.nextDouble();
if (income <= 25000)
incomeStatus = true;
else
incomeStatus = false;

//Prompt the user to enter the hourly rate
System.out.println("Enter hourly rate:");
hourlyRate= input.nextDouble();

//Prompt the total consulting time
System.out.println("Enter total consluting time(minutes):");
consultingTime= input.nextDouble();

System.out.println("The billing amount is : $"+billingAmount(hourlyRate, consultingTime, incomeStatus));
}

public static void stoporgo() {
    System.out.println("Do you want to Continue or Stop:");
    String s = "";{
    while(!s.equals("Stop"))
    break;
        s = console.next();

    }
}
public static String sayGreeting() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to A&A Accounting");
        System.out.println("Glad to help you determine your cost for filing 2012 taxes with us");

    return null;
}
/*Method takes as input the hourly rate , the total consulting time
* and a value indicating if the person has low income */
public static double billingAmount(double hourlyRate, double consultingTime,boolean incomeStatus)
{
double charges;
if(incomeStatus)

/* If low income (<=25,000) and the consulting time
* is less than or equal to 30 minutes
* there are no charges
*/
if(consultingTime <= 30)
charges = 0.0;

/*Otherwise the service charges are 40% of the
* regular hourly rate for the time over 30 minutes .
*/
else
charges = hourlyRate * 0.4 *
(consultingTime - 30) / 60;
/*, if the consulting time is less that or equal to 20 minutes
* there are two service charges ; otherwise service charges
* are 70% of the regular hourly rate for the time over 20 minutes

* */
else if (consultingTime <= 20)
charges =0.0;
else
charges = hourlyRate * 0.7 *
(consultingTime - 20) / 60;

return charges;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The following pseudocode must be followed to get full credit for the program;
public class programOne{
declare all finals here.
public static void main (String[] args ) {
declare all variables here.
call a void greeting method
call a method that returns either stop or continue from the user
while (answer equals continue){
 call a method that return the yearly income, the user must enter the value
 call a method that returns the hourly rate, user must enter the value
 call a method that returns the consulting time in minutes user must enter the value
 call a method that determines the billing
 call a method that prints the output
 call a method that returns either stop or continue from the user}//end of while
Call a goodbye void method
}//end of main
Definition of all other methods goes here!
}//end of class
```